# Git client still try to use proxy after I unset the http.proxy

Tags: git, version-control

I am using git on windows. Several days ago, I set a proxy for the git with:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://......
git config --global https.proxy http://.....
```

Today, My proxy server is down. I have to unset it. but the git client still try to connect the proxy after unsetted it.

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

The error is

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/gogits/gogs.git/': Failed
>   to connect to proxy server port 8080: Bad access

Anyone knows how to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

Might be you are having proxy in the local config, try running following commands:

```
git config --unset http.proxy
git config --unset https.proxy
```

And verify the variables set in config file, along with their values, for both local and global:

```
git config --global --list
git config --local --list
```